# ggvis add_legend for 'strokeDash' or 'strokeWidth'

Tags: r, legend, ggvis

I want to group data on two variables and distinguish them in a ggvis plot via 'stroke' and 'strokeDash'. If I want to add legends to a ggvis plot, I can do so for the 'stroke' property:

```
library(ggvis)

mtcars %>% 
  ggvis(~wt, ~mpg, stroke = ~factor(cyl), strokeDash = ~factor(vs)) %>%
  layer_lines() %>%
  add_legend('stroke', title = 'Number of cylinders')
```

However, if try to add a legend for 'strokeDash', the plot does not get rendered:

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggvis(~wt, ~mpg, stroke = ~factor(cyl), strokeDash = ~factor(vs)) %>%
  layer_lines() %>%
  add_legend('stroke', title = 'Number of cylinders') %>%
  add_legend('strokeDash', title = 'V/S')
```

Same applies, if I try it with 'strokeWidth' instead of 'strokeDash':

```
# works
mtcars %>% 
  ggvis(~wt, ~mpg, stroke = ~factor(cyl), strokeWidth = ~factor(vs)) %>%
  layer_lines() %>%
  scale_nominal('strokeWidth', range = c(1,5)) %>% 
  add_legend('stroke', title = 'Number of cylinders')

# does not work
mtcars %>% 
  ggvis(~wt, ~mpg, stroke = ~factor(cyl), strokeWidth = ~factor(vs)) %>%
  layer_lines() %>%
  scale_nominal('strokeWidth', range = c(1,5)) %>% 
  add_legend('stroke', title = 'Number of cylinders')%>%
  add_legend('strokeWidth', title = 'V/S')
```

Does anyone know, why for 'stroke' it works and for the others it does not? Any solutions?

Thanks, 
Fabian

Comment: Based on this open [github issue](https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues/187), it looks like you currently may not be able to have a legend for `strokeDash`.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the hint!